# FFmpeg: ffmpeg binary not found Error

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-conversion

**What I Have:**
 - I have built and installed **FFmpeg** on windows following this documentation [FFmpeg](http://python-video-converter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html).
 - I am implementing video upload in my python/django project and I need to accept all extensions of videos, convert them to **MP4**, save and view them in the **video** html element.

**Error I get:**
 - I first import the converter from the installed library:

```
from converter import Converter
```

- Then I get an error (FFMpegError: ffmpeg binary not found: ffmpeg) when I execute:

```
c = Converter()
```

Any solution please!

Comment: do you `ffmpeg` in your `%PATH%`?

Comment: Actually No, and what to put, I mean what path? Where can I find the bin of ffmpeg?

Comment: Worked after providing the path of bin.